# Insert results from select query, which is already changed

Tags: postgresql

I want to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO contacts_fields (
  contact_id, field_name, numeric_value
)
select distinct      
  c.id, 
  'storeId', 
  1
from 
  contacts c 
  inner join contacts_devices cd on cd.contact_id = c.id 
  and c.id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
      contact_id 
    FROM 
      contacts_fields
  )
group by 
  c.id
```

But I am getting an error:

```
SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: insert or update on table "contact_fields" violates foreign key constraint "contacts_fields_fkey"
Detail: Key (contact_id)=(2425542) is not present in table "contacts".
```

This is propably because `contacts` table is changing all the time, any maybe I can't insert value with `2425542`, becasuse it was deleted between `select` and `insert` query. What can I do with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Re-attempt the query and hope to win the race.

   or
2. Add `FOR UPDATE` to the end of the `SELECT` to cause all referenced rows to be locked for the duration of the transaction. The performance implications are significant if the tables are large, and success is not 100% guaranteed, but the window of opportunity for conflict is very, very small.

If your `SELECT` is very slow then it increases the window for conflict.

I'm also seeing the EAV [anti-pattern](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/03/database-modelization-anti-patterns/) in `contacts_fields`, which should be the subject of another question.